# Storing multiple values into Dictionary

Tags: excel, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am new to python and am facing difficulties in dictionary. I am trying to store multiple values from excel into dictionary.

This is my input:

[image]

And i am trying to store in this way.

My expected output is:

```
d = [
{
"name":"dhdn",
"sub":["c","java","python"]
},
{
"name":"subbu",
"sub":["java","perl"]
}
]
```

I tried like this:

```
df_service = pd.read_excel(existing_excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_service = df_service.replace(np.nan, "dummy")
print(df_service)

list1 = []

for i in range(0, len(df_service['name'])):
    dict1 = {}
    lst = []
    if df_service['name'][i] != 'dummy':        
        dict1["name"] = df_service['name'][i]
        lst.append(df_service['sub'][i])
    else:
        lst.append(df_service['sub'][i])
    dict1["sub"] = lst
    list1.append(dict1)

print(list1)
```

And what if the excel data is like given below:

[image]

What if we have data like this? How to create a dictionary for this?

Need some suggestion, not getting any idea.

Comment: That's going to depend on how you're getting the values themselves from the csv/excel-file. Could you provide some additional code, so that we know what our input is?

Comment: @HampusLarsson the input will be in .xlsx. One key having more than one value. I am updating my question with tried code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_service = df_service.fillna(method='ffill')
result = [{'name':k[0],'usn':k[1],'sub':v["sub"].tolist(),"marks":v["marks"].tolist()} for k,v in df_service.groupby(['name', 'usn'])]
pprint (result)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.fillna with the method='ffill' option. 'ffill' stands for 'forward fill' and will propagate last valid observation forward.

```
df_service = pd.read_excel(existing_excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1')

df_service = df_service.fillna(method='ffill')
result = [{'name':k,'sub':g["sub"].tolist()} for k,g in df_service.groupby("name")]
print (result)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'dhdn', 'sub': ['c', 'java', 'python']}, {'name': 'subbu', 'sub': ['java', 'perl']}]
```

Comment: Hi @ncica, I tried your way to answer but I am unable to apply logic in the mentioned format. can you please help me to create a dictionary for above-posted question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi @ncica, I appreciate your answer, what if we have data like this? How to create a dictionary for this.